# Rails has disappeared

Tags: ruby-on-rails, installation, system

I developed a web in rails and it was working perfectly for months. Now I went to my web folder and started "rails server" but got the reply:

> Rails is not currently installed on this system. To get the latest version, simply type:
>     $ sudo gem install rails

I really don't understand how rails could disappeared from my system, I am sure I haven't removed it. I was using rails 3.1 on a Mac. Any clues or suggestions?

Gemfile:

```
source 'rubygems.org';
gem 'rails', '3.1.0.rc5'
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

#group :test, :production do
# gem 'mysql', '5.1.58'
#end

#group :development do gem 'sqlite3'
#end

#gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter
gem 'json'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.1.0.rc"
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0.rc"
  gem 'uglifier'
end

gem 'jquery-rails'
```

Comment: How did you install ruby and rails? What OS are you using? Did you use a package manager? RVM? We need more info before we can even begin to speculate…

Comment: Try `bundle exec rails server`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Bundle install results in: bundle is complete, 
including ,,Using rails (3.1.0.rc5)" and ,,bundle show rails" points to the folder where it is supposed to be, that is /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/rails-3.1.0.rc5 which is on the PATH environment variable. Still I cannot run rails.
bundle exec rails server results in
Could not find rake-0.9.2 in any of the sources
Operating system: Mac OS X 10.6.8

Comment: What does your Gemfile look like?

Comment: source 'http://rubygems.org'  
gem 'rails', '3.1.0.rc5'  
# gem 'rails',     :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'  
#group :test, :production do  
# gem 'mysql', '5.1.58'  
#end    
#group :development do  
 gem 'sqlite3'  
#end  
#gem install activerecord-mysql-adapter  
gem 'json'  
# Gems used only for assets and not required  
# in production environments by default.  
group :assets do  
  gem 'sass-rails', "~> 3.1.0.rc"  
  gem 'coffee-rails', "~> 3.1.0.rc"  
  gem 'uglifier'  
end  
gem 'jquery-rails'

Comment: are you using RVM? If so, can you check that your bash_profile still references RVM?

Answer (score 0):

I have faced a similar problem.
I believe rails 3.1.0 is buggy, i myself tried my hands on it and reverted back to the stable version of rails i.e. anything but 3.1.0. It would have been better if you have installed RVM. With RVM you can have one or more rails version, in fact an entire gemset.

I myself have a global gemset and another gemset named rails1.

`rvm gemset create gemset_name`

Once you install the like of ruby and rails version you can set it default

`rvm gemset default@gemset_name`

I did this back then and it works fine on my end. [More on RVM](http://beginrescueend.com/gemsets/creating/)

Hope it helps.